# Как установить количество товара по умолчанию в Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, acf

У меня есть поле, созданное через ACF. Туда выгружается число, которое должно подставляться в поле количества товара и быть как-бы "по умолчанию" для данного товара, но должна сохраниться возможность его редактировать (+/-).

Использую данный код:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'rb_woocommerce_quantity_changes', 10, 2 );
function rb_woocommerce_quantity_changes( $args, $product ) {

    $attribute = get_field('middle_sq'); 

    if( ! is_cart() )
        if (($attribute !== "") and ($attribute !== 0)){
            $args['input_value'] = $attribute; // Not on cart page, cuz throw critical error
    }


//    $args['input_value'] = $attribute;
    $args['min_value'] = 1;
    $args['step'] = 1;
    return $args;
}
```

Он отлично работает если зайти на страницу товара (single-product) и добавить товар в корзину оттуда. Товар добавляться с нужным количеством.

Но **проблема в том**, что если товар добавляется со страницы архива или из лупа с похожими товарами (под карточкой товара), то в корзину, все равно, добавляется товар с количеством 1.

Как можно это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что когда Вы находитесь в товаре, то $attribute = get_field('middle_sq');  отрабатывает относительно главного цикла, где есть есть уже айди_товара. Нужно модифицировать хук, чтоб вызывался с айди_товара.

Например, так

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'rb_woocommerce_quantity_changes', 10, 2 );

function rb_woocommerce_quantity_changes( $args, $product ) {
    
    $product_id = $product->is_type('variation') ? $product->get_parent_id() : $product->get_id();

    $attribute = get_field('middle_sq', $product_id); 

    if( ! is_cart() )
        if (($attribute !== "") and ($attribute !== 0)){
            $args['input_value'] = $attribute; // Not on cart page, cuz throw critical error
    }


//    $args['input_value'] = $attribute;
    $args['min_value'] = 1;
    $args['step'] = 1;
    return $args;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо информацию и за ваш ответ